# Django form : add new objects for a many-to-many field

Tags: django-models, django-forms, many-to-many, django-views

I am trying to create an app where I have Organizations and Roles, which have a many to many relationship, i.e the same role can exist in many organizations, and one organization can have many roles. To get entries, I want the user to fill up a form for an Organization, where he defines the name of the Organization and can then choose pre-existing roles, or add new ones.

How do I add new options for Role while defining an Organization if the ones already there are not enough?

I have the following models:

```
Class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    roles = models.ManyToManyField('Role',blank=True)
    owner_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    owner_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    owner = generic.GenericForeignKey('owner_type', 'owner_id')

Class Role(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

These are the forms:

```
class OrganizationForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta :
    model = Context
    exclude = ('owner_type','owner_id','owner')

def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = user # get user here!
    super(OrganizationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def save(self,commit = True):
    new_org = super(OrganizationForm,self).save(commit=False)
    new_org.owner = self.user
    if commit:
        new_org.save()
    return new_org
```

This is the view I have so far,

```
def add_organization(request,template_name = "home/editorg.html"):
if request.POST:
    form = OrganizationForm(request.user,request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        org = form.save(commit=False)
        org.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return HttpResponse('Entry made')
else:
    form = OrganizationForm()
    return render_to_response(template_name,{"form": form })
```